# USB device connecting and disconnecting repeatedly

Tags: boot, usb, fsck, recovery-mode, disconnect

I was having some problems booting into Ubuntu. After trying to reboot for sometime, I eventually opened the 4.4.0-31 recovery mode. while it was booting into recovery mode, it said that `/dev/ubuntu-gnome-vg` needs to `fsck` manually.

While this was going on the touchscreen for the computer was connecting and disconnecting repeatedly.

The screen was showing this:

```
usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 42 using using xchi_hcd
usb 2-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idproduct=016f
usb 2-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product =14, SerialNumber=0
usb 2-7: Product: Touchscreen
usb 2-7: Manufacturer: ELAN
usb 2-7: ep 0x2 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc
says 80 microframes 
usb 2-7: USB disconnect, device number 42.
```

and then this repeats with the device being 43.

How do I stop this so that I can actually try and fix the problem on the disk. Also if you guys have some advice regarding /dev/ubuntu-gnome-vg needing to be fsck'd that be great.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspiciously similar like a broken USB cable or port. I can say that for sure because I'm using such: every time I'm touching a cable of my USB hub, I see in `/var/log/syslog` a wall of those messages about *(dis)* connection, and increasing device number; and the connected mouse resets its sensitivity.

Just for the record, here's an example of mine log:

```
Aug 20 17:22:38 constantine-N61Ja kernel: [55857.366422] usb 4-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 25        
Aug 20 17:22:38 constantine-N61Ja kernel: [55857.366428] usb 4-1.1.2: USB disconnect, device number 26      
Aug 20 17:22:38 constantine-N61Ja kernel: [55857.366730] usb 4-1.1.3: USB disconnect, device number 27      
Aug 20 17:22:39 constantine-N61Ja kernel: [55857.690545] usb 4-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 28 using ehci-pci
Aug 20 17:22:39 constantine-N61Ja kernel: [55857.774736] hub 4-1.1:1.0: USB hub found                       
Aug 20 17:22:39 constantine-N61Ja kernel: [55857.774788] hub 4-1.1:1.0: 4 ports detected                    
Aug 20 17:22:39 constantine-N61Ja kernel: [55858.043972] usb 4-1.1.2: new low-speed USB device number 29 using ehci-pci
Aug 20 17:22:39 constantine-N61Ja kernel: [55858.142289] input: HID 192f:0716 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.2/4-1.1.2:1.0/0003:192F:0716.0019/input/input49
Aug 20 17:22:39 constantine-N61Ja kernel: [55858.142518] hid-generic 0003:192F:0716.0019: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [HID 192f:0716] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1.2/input0
Aug 20 17:22:39 constantine-N61Ja kernel: [55858.207327] usb 4-1.1.3: new low-speed USB device number 30 using ehci-pci
Aug 20 17:22:39 constantine-N61Ja kernel: [55858.320867] input:   USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.3/4-1.1.3:1.0/0003:04D9:1702.001A/input/input50                                                                                                                                     
Aug 20 17:22:39 constantine-N61Ja kernel: [55858.374364] hid-generic 0003:04D9:1702.001A: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [  USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1.3/input0                                                                                                                                           
Aug 20 17:22:39 constantine-N61Ja kernel: [55858.391406] input:   USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.3/4-1.1.3:1.1/0003:04D9:1702.001B/input/input51
Aug 20 17:22:39 constantine-N61Ja kernel: [55858.444140] hid-generic 0003:04D9:1702.001B: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [  USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1.3/input1
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but in  an arch-based linux, the difference is in my case, it randomly disconnect and connect sometimes, without doing anytihng

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily disconnect your touchscreen device from its USB port. Then boot the computer into RECOVERY mode from the GRUB menu, choose ROOT, then type **sudo fsck -f /dev/ubuntu-gnome-vg**. Let us know how that works. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

A faulty cable might cause this.

It might also be a power problem.  I've had better luck with some USB thumb drives since switching to a powered USB hub.